# Clickonce signing manifest

Tags: clickonce

Can some tell the steps to sign my clickonce app?

If buy a certificate from someone how do I install it
on my dev box and also the server where I want it to go on??

Please outline steps.

Malcolm

Answer (score 2):

Here are the outlined steps I believe you are after - [How to: Sign Application and Deployment Manifests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/che5h906.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I found this [blog post](http://www.softinsight.com/bnoyes/2006/06/23/ManagingClickOncePublisherCertificateFiles.aspx) from Brian Noyes extremely useful.  It details how to take a 
purchased certificate and create a .pfx file you can use to sign ClickOnce manifests.